# Insert a blank page after current page

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, blank-page

I want to insert a blank page in a document so that the text would be added to the content of the current page till it reaches end of the page, the next page would be empty, and the text continue from the third page!

If I used `\afterpage{\newpage}` but it just does not work!
what should I do?

Comment: Do you want the page counter to increment across the blank page, e.g., to go from p.7 to p. 9?

Comment: This page contains a few solutions that I found helpful https://zhiganglu.com/post/latex-insert-blank-page/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You should use the `afterpage` package.

In the preamble :

```
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
```

In the text before the blank page, insert the following code:

```
\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

It should do the trick. Be aware that unresolved floats might be a trouble here.

Comment: How to reduce page counter within preliminaries where page numbers are roman?

Comment: @fatih Did you try to use the solution provided? What is the issue?

Comment: @Martigan Yes, I did. The problem was with another patch I applied together with this one. It appeared that the former was incrementing the page counter, effectively compensating the decrement in this solution. So the solution works for me also. Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of using `\afterpage{}`? It seems that `\blankpage` on its own does the job.

Comment: @BillWallis It is important since you do not want to remove the style and numerotation of the active page when you input blankpage... You want it to be done after the current page is done. I suggest you try both, and you will see the difference very clearly (at last if you do it in several cases).

Comment: When I do it it adds two pages instead of one.

Comment: @skan Did you add the code in the text of the page, or at the end of it?

Comment: \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\begin{appendices} 
\end{appendices}

Comment: It may very well be that, since the afterpage is indeed after the final word of the text (and worse, after a complete sequence of complex formatting operations), there is an unresolved blank float and it doubles the effect. I can't try this right now.

Comment: Dear Martigan, what should I do if I want the blank page to be counted ??? Thank you very much ?

Comment: @AnKhuongDoan Juste remove the line :    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%

Comment: I needed an additional `\clearpage` after this trick to make sure the pages did not get mixed up. The blank page got inserted somewhere later.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Was it always the case? Or was it only from time to time? Again, sometimes unresolved floats can still cause issue

Comment: @Martigan I tried to insert two blank pages at the very beginning of a document, followed by an included pdf containing a 3 title pages. The blank pages ended up between the first page of the PDF and the last two. Doing `\afterpage{\blankpage}\clearpage` fixed that. I don't know if included PDFs behave like floats, but yeah, this is what happened for me.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I believe the fact that this is the very first thing you do may be the issue. I have to admit my understanding of the deeper inner workings of LateX is low, so I can't explain. You found a solution, that is the main news!

Comment: @Martigan Good job! What if I want the blank page to have the page number? For example, if it comes after `iv` in the preamble and I want it to have the page number `v`. Currently, it is empty, and the page next to it carries the  `v`.

Comment: @arilwan Not sure completely, I have no way to test it out right now. You might want to remove the line with $\thispagestyle{empty}%$. And of course remove the line $\addtocounter{page}{-1}%$.

Answer (score 44):

You just need something – anything – before or after the `\newpage` command. Try

```
\afterpage{\null\newpage}
```

Of course, this doesn’t remove page numbers or headers and footers, and it does increase the page number. If you don’t want this, see Martigan’s solution.

Answer (score 41):

Just use `\newpage \ \newpage`:

```
my current page

\newpage 

\ % The empty page

\newpage

The next page
```

Comment: I think this is the most simplest way.

Comment: short and sweet solution!

Comment: This solution is exactly what I need!

Comment: Simple, violent, but useful!

Comment: Sadly, page number will be printed using this approach.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni  add `\thispagestyle{empty}` to avoid printing page number.

Answer (score 22):

I think you can avoid using the `afterpage` package. In the preamble, write:

```
\def\blankpage{%
      \clearpage%
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
      \null%
      \clearpage}
```

In the `document` environment, use the `\blankpage` command to add blank pages without style or counting.

Answer (score 10):

What's about

```
\leavevmode\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
```

?

Comment: That will make a page break at the current point, not after the page has been filled.

Comment: Add a space before it. It worked for me.