# Openright in oneside book

Tags: chapters, books

I'm using book with the oneside option.
Although, I'm using the oneside option I would like to start the chapters in odd pages only (like if the openright option was enabled).

Apparently, the openright option does not work because with oneside all pages are right. 
Do you know how to solve it?

best,

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4, 11pt,oneside,openright]{book}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{First}
  \chapter{Second}
  \chapter{Third}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't really see much sense in this; are you using `oneside` just for having equal margins on both sides?

Comment: @egreg yes, I guess. Or at least, that's what I am doing. Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `\cleardoublepage` - responsible for properly clearing pages to a recto page - checks whether you're using the `twoside` option or not (alternatively, `oneside`). If we strip this conditional `twoside` from the definition (available in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)), you achieve your goal:

```
% Taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

So add the above to your preamble.

[image]

A somewhat similar approach would be to set the `twoside` option temporarily to true during a `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{{\@twosidetrue\oldcleardoublepage}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks it did work perfectly. Just mention that, since the document has a titlepage and I'm using the oneside option, I inserted a blankpage after the titlepage (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/insert-a-blank-page-after-current-page) in order to make it work.