# Leaving the current page empty and starting on the next

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, lyx, page-breaking, windows

I'm trying to format a document in lyx so that each chapter or section begins on its own page. Following this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/insert-a-blank-page-after-current-page) and adding the following to the latex preamble:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
```

but when I try to add an empty page after the Abstract, so that the contents table will be displayed on the next and not on the same with the abstract, what happens is that part of the contents table is added until the page containing the abstract is filled, a blank page is added afterwards and then the remainder of the contents table is shown.

How can I add the contents table on its own page?

Currently, I add

```
\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

immediately after the abstract and

```
\tableofcontents
```

immediately after the blank page primitive.

Comment: Just put \newpage after the Abtract, etc.  The referenced answer was to create a blank page between two pages.

Comment: Add `\clearpage` before `\null` (it would be better to use `\vspace*{\fill}` instead of `\null`, which is not a documented LaTeX command).

Comment: You should not need to use \afterpage here. It is the default for almost all classes that have chapters for the chapter to start on a new right hand page, leaving a blank if necessary.

Comment: @John Kormylo that worked :)

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `afterpage` package at all here, just use the standard `\clearpage` command before `\tableofcontents`.