# Text underneath pdf when using includepdf

Tags: graphics, pdfpages, include

I'm using includepdf to include a table.

```
\includepdf[pages={1} ]{table.pdf}
```

However, this results in the text running underneath the pdf.

[image]

Using `/clearpage` or `/newpage` results in ghastly blank spaces before or after the inclusion of the pdf page.

Edit:

This doesn't work:

```
\afterpage{%
\includepdf[pages={1} ]{table.pdf}
\clearpage
}
```

Edit2:

I think the problem is with the two columns. Using

```
\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

From this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/insert-a-blank-page-after-current-page), I only have one blank column and the same issue.

Comment: You really need to provide a MWE. Provide which document class, what size, how many columns, and other essential setup details. Also, is the included PDF the same page size as the TeX document? Does the finished file need to be formatted for an E-journal, or not?