# Only the last chapter 6 has no blank pages with Chapter 5 and bibliography

Tags: blank-page

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}        
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\newcommand\floor[1]{\lfloor#1\rfloor}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[setpagesize=false]{hyperref}

\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{21cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{29.7cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}
%---throrem
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\include{cover}
\thispagestyle{empty} \normalfont \cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \cleardoublepage
\include{thanks}
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \normalfont \cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ 
\thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}         
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\include{chapter1} 
\include{chapter2} 
\include{chapter3} 
\include{chapter4} 
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}



\cleardoublepage
% ---- Bibliography ----
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{biblio}
%\nocite{*}

\appendix

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyfoot{}                                               
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\appendixname\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}         
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your exemple, while it compiles with latex, doesn't help: we don't have access to the \include'd files so can't see the problem you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this behavior is caused by the combination of the `openright` option and the `\cleardoublepage`.

It is hard to verify without the actual sources, but does chapter six end on an even numbered page and the other chapters on odd numbered pages?

The `openright` option ensures that every chapter start on a right (odd numbered) page.

The command `\doublepage` has the following behavior (emphasis mine):

> The `\cleardoublepage` command ends the current page and causes all figures and tables that have so far appeared in the input to be printed. In a two-sided printing style, it also makes the next page a right-hand (odd-numbered) page, **producing a blank page if necessary.**

E.g. the `\doublepage` *only* creates a blank page when necessary.

When I compiled your sources with some random input for the chapters this was the behavior I saw and is the intended behavior of the `openright` option.

If you would really like to insert an empty page you could look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/insert-a-blank-page-after-current-page%22here%22).