# Odd blank page after abstract

Tags: abstract, blank-page

I've got a problem with the formatting of the following MWI. I would like to have:

1. Page: Abstract with header and title        -> done
2. Page: completely blank                                 -> **not done, header still visible**
3. Page: Second abstract with header and title -> done
4. Page: completely blank                                 -> **not done, header still visible**
5. Page - end: full header, titles, texts      -> done

So I think it might be a problem that I have redefined the pagestyle plain, but this was necessary to obtain the header on the first chapter pages...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%Layout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}

%Header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Chapter adjustments
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{0}\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{9pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{16pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Formatting the header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\fontsize{8}{5} \selectfont \thepage}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\fontsize{8}{5} \selectfont \leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\fontsize{8}{5} \selectfont \thepage}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\fontsize{8}{5} \selectfont \leftmark}
}

%Abstracttexts
\newcommand{\FirstAbstract}{This is Abstract 1.}
\newcommand{\SecondAbstract}{This is Abstract 2.}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

%Abstract 1
{\fontsize{16pt}{0} \selectfont {\bf Abstract 1}}
\newline \vspace{-2mm} \\
\FirstAbstract
\markboth{First Abstract}{}
\cleardoublepage

%Abstract 2
\newpage 
{\fontsize{16pt}{0} \selectfont {\bf Abstract 2}}
\newline \vspace{-2mm} \\
\SecondAbstract
\markboth{Second Abstract}{}
\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{First Section}
\blindtext
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try loading titlesec with option `clearempty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : Bernard's solution works just fine, that is replacing `\usepackage{titlesec}` by `\usepackage[clearempty]{titlesec}`

---

You could use [Martigan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5526/martigan)'s solution in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/insert-a-blank-page-after-current-page/36881) to create a new command for a completely blank page. To do this, add

```latex
%blank page
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
```

to your preamble.

Now replace `\cleardoublepage` by the newly defined command : `\afterpage{\blankpage}`.

For example, for the first Abstract :

```latex
%Abstract 1
{\fontsize{16pt}{0} \selectfont {\bf Abstract 1}}
\newline \vspace{-2mm} \\
\FirstAbstract
\markboth{First Abstract}{}
\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly I was searching for, I just deleted \addtocounter{page}{-1} because the page numbering should continue, if anyone wonders about the same :)

Comment: Using the relevant option for `titlesec`, which is  already loaded, does the same job, without additional code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much! I have adjusted my code to shorten it :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to load `emptypage`.

I also suggest some fixes: use `\chapter*{Abstract 1}` instead of manually emulating the typesetting of a chapter header. I also fixed the parameters to `\fontsize`: if you use `\fontsize{8}{5}` for the header, there will be no gap between the header and the rule.

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%Layout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}

%Header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}

%Chapter adjustments
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{16}{20}\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{9pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{16pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Formatting the header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \thepage}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \thepage}%
  \fancyhead[ER,OL]{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \leftmark}%
}

%Abstracttexts
\newcommand{\FirstAbstract}{This is Abstract 1.}
\newcommand{\SecondAbstract}{This is Abstract 2.}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

%Abstract 1
\chapter*{Abstract 1}%
\chaptermark{First Abstract}

\FirstAbstract

\cleardoublepage

%Abstract 2
\chapter*{Abstract 2}%
\chaptermark{Second Abstract}

\SecondAbstract

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{First Section}
\blindtext
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the additional improvement proposals, I adapted them! :-)